# How to finetune the fast api using Uvicorn server

Tags: python, fastapi, unicorn

I have created one Restapi to convert English to arabic comments using NLP Marian MT model. The
api has been deployed to linux server with 12 workers in uvicorn server. The problem I facing that sometime it is taking more time (like 12 seconds) to get the response from api. I am expecting to get the response in 2 seconds.

**How I can tune the response time.**

Comment: The best thing is to write a test for your methods and run the tests with profiler. Then you can analyze which parts of your code take most time. Running a profiler on a production server is not a clever idea.